TimeInterval to Date conversion not giving accurate result
I am getting the TimeInterval from API, and getting the converted Date through the below code.
let dateObj = timeInterval.getSinceTimeAgoDate()) // ex: timeInterval = 1566203990527
extension TimeInterval {
    func getSinceTimeAgoDate() -> String {
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: self/1000)
        return date.sortTimeAgoSinceDate()
    }
}


    func sortTimeAgoSinceDate() -> String {
        
        // From Time
        let fromDate = self
        
        // To Time
        let toDate = Date()
        
        // Estimation
        // Year
        if let interval = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: fromDate, to: toDate).year, interval > 0  {
            return "\(interval)" + "y"
        }
        
        // Month
        if let interval = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: fromDate, to: toDate).month, interval > 0  {
            return "\(interval)" + "M"
        }
        
        // Day
        if let interval = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: fromDate, to: toDate).day, interval > 0  {
            return "\(interval)" + "d"
        }
        
        // Hours
        if let interval = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: fromDate, to: toDate).hour, interval > 0 {
            return "\(interval)" + "h"
        }
        
        // Minute
        if let interval = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: fromDate, to: toDate).minute, interval > 0 {
            return "\(interval)" + "m"
        }
        
        return  "Just Now"
    }

The above method give result : 4 year
While checking on https://www.epochconverter.com/ the result is 5 Year
Can some body check and let me know what I'm doing not right here.
with time interval 1566203990527 reult should be 5 year
Expected Result is
GMT: Monday, August 19, 2019 8:39:50.527 AM
Your time zone: Monday, August 19, 2019 2:09:50.527 PM GMT+05:30
Relative: 5 years ago



Hint: Your code is not checking for dates before and after Feb 28th so it is broken. The whole approach is misguided.

It’s about 4 years 11 months and 2 weeks between the two so if you want the result to be 5 years you need to I implement rounding.

@gnasher729 could you share the correct working method.?

extension Date {
func timeAgoDisplay() -> String {
let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .full
return formatter.localizedString(for: self, relativeTo: Date())
}
}
@gnasher729 this method also giving the same solution means there is no issue of feb month.
